# Why does the menubar hide when I'm in iTunes?

Tags: snow-leopard, menu-bar, itunes

Often when I'm using iTunes 10.4, the menubar will hide and show like the dock does when you set it that way. I don't know of any settings that allow for that to happen on the menubar. Is it a bug or a setting that I accidentaly changed?

Comment: What operating system are you running? What version of iTunes?

Comment: Snow Leopard, iTunes 10.4

Comment: Using any plugins?

Comment: no, no plugins, etc. Another user has SuperTunes installed, but I have never used it.

Comment: You're not using the full-screen modus by any chance, are you?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior you describe in a different user account? Create a dummy user account and use iTunes from there. Does the problem persist?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running iTunes in full screen mode if you're on Lion. In the top right corner you should have a button with two arrows that allows you to switch between full screen mode and regular mode.

Comment: Nope, I'm on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

*If this is due to a setting or false install, try this:*

Use an advanced cleaning to **fully remove** iTunes:
**AppCleaner** http://freemacsoft.net/#

Then **reinstall** iTunes.

This will not delete your music, movies, apps! Only the program.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I recommend a much better way to do this: uncheck iTunes's app bundle. No need for a reinstall, and app bundle's don't store any computer specific data, so it'll be just like a fresh install

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX That's great! I've been doing this sort of alternative re-install several times now and it has helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

On the left top corner you see the square button half black half clear colour,press that button you will see the option available ,select "the show menu bar ",it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

.. just maximize your iTune window , and move the mouse to the top of the screen, then you see the menu bar drop down, when you move the mouse away it disappears again. (iTune 11x)

Answer (score -1):

just move the cursor to the top border of the screen